# Calling Azure AD secured web API with client / secret

Tags: c#, oauth, azure-active-directory

I've been at this whole day and it's driving me NUTS. I've got a web API published on Azure which is secured with Azure AD authentication. I've been using this API in combination with a mobile app for quite a while now. On the mobile app, I use the library for client authentication (Microsoft account which is in AD) and this works perfectly. Within the app, API requests are authenticated with the `X-ZUMO-AUTH` header.

Now for a new part of the application, I've got a C# console app which also needs to be able to call the app. This needs to run stand-alone, so without asking for user credentials. So I created an application in Azure AD, gave it permissions to the Web API instance and got me some code to get an authentication token. That token is then passed into the `HttpClient` object:

```
AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientID, clientSecret);
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await ac.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred);
string authToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, endpoint);
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authToken);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Server auth is set-up like this:

```
string aadTenant = configProvider.GetConfigurationSettingValue("ida.Tenant");
string aadAudience = configProvider.GetConfigurationSettingValue("ida.Audience");

app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
    new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
    { 
        Tenant = aadTenant,
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidAudience = aadAudience
        },
    });
```

I have triple checked all the variables. I also verified that the Bearer token is correctly passed to the service (Fiddler shows it). Everything seems absolutely fine, but still, the server keeps responding with **Unauthorized**.

My hunch is that this has something to do with the Web API. It's been set up as mobile services back-end. I'm suspecting that this is somehow interfering with 'normal' authentication schemes and the `401` is coming from mobile services not understanding this authentication request, even though the bearer authentication has been setup. But this is just a hunch and I'm not sure whether it actually makes sense or not.

I've seen the related questions on this topic, and all of the samples ([used this one](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon) as the primary source of inspiration). I've tried all of the variations out there, to no avail. So what I'm looking for is ways to find out where the actual problem is. "Unauthorized" is a bit vague to say the least, so I'm trying to find out why the calls are returned with this response. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Additional endpoint info**

As requested, here's some info on the endpoints I'm using:

```
authority = https://login.microsoftonline.com/{aad-tenant-name}
```

Also tried the OAuth2 token endpoints listed on the management page:

```
authority = https://login.microsoftonline.com/{aad-guid}/oauth2/token

authority = https://login.microsoftonline.com/{aad-guid}/oauth2/authorize
```

For the client, information I'm passing in the `ClientID` and generated secret I got from the AAD Application page for the application I created. I have granted the application permissions to access the App Service instance for my web API endpoint. Those calls are going to:

```
https://{app service url}.azurewebsites.net/api/controller
```

<strike>Whilst trying to get this going I noticed more weird behavior. I thought for now I'd just set this particular controller to [AllowAnonymous] so that I could call it without any authentication. But when I do so and omit passing in the Bearer token, I still get Unauthorized as response. That kind of enforces my idea that there's something wrong on the server side and that this might have something to do with how the mobile app stuff is strapped to the webapi controllers.</strike>

Never mind, the controller being forced to authorize was caused by Web App level authentication settings, [documented here](http://blog.repsaj.nl/index.php/2016/05/web-api-controller-hosted-in-azure-not-respecting-allowanonymous/)

Comment: what's your request or show your endpoint value? make sure your accesstoken has permission to access endpoint. I see your code no problem

Comment: Updated post with more info about the endpoints. Is there some way to "decode" or analyze the access token I'm getting to find out more about the permissions?

Comment: Your accesstoken only access api from Azure, like resource=`https://management.core.windows.net/` ,endpoint=`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subscriptionid/resourceGroups?api-version=2015-12-01` or resource=`https://graph.windows.net/`, endpoint=`https://graph.windows.net/tenantid/users?api-version=1.6`

Comment: you could use these simple api to confirm if your accesstoken is right, more infor refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974476.aspx

Comment: Ok. I've verified that I was able to call the Graph API using those credentials, so the token is ok. But does that mean I cannot call my own endpoint? Or do I need to do something extra to get this to work?

Comment: I said your accesstoken only access api from Azure and only get information from azure. What's `https://{app service url}.azurewebsites.net/api/controller`, do you want to call it?

Comment: Yes that is the endpoint I want to call. It's an ASP.NET MVC application running in Azure (App Service). It is secured using the same Azure AD instance where normally a user needs to sign in with a valid account.

Comment: What you can call depends on:
1. What you've granted you app permissions to via application permissions (since you are using Client Credentials) at config time.
2. What resource you request access to at runtime.

For #1, did you define application permissions for your API and then check those permissions in your web apps application permissions config?

For #2, you need to make sure you specify your app's URI as the resource.

Comment: Also, check you have the latest package of Microsoft.Owin and any other Azure AD required assemblies. I would start with a new Web API project and use the same config file to test